# HP Photosmart 5520 OS X 10.5.8 driver

Tags: macos, printing, leopard

My mom bought a HP Photosmart 5520. Unfortunately, this printer is not compatible with her OS X 10.5.8 system.

Is there a possibility we can get this working?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with a HP Photosmart 5520 install diskette requiring (the 64bit architecture) Mountain Lion, Lion, etc.  You can start the install with the install diskette, it will soon just finish as a 5520 with NO Functionality. While an older version photosmart driver is the best bet, be sure it has a wireless functionality (e.g older Photosmarts C4400 etc. did not work) You will need a WIRELESS supporting driver, viz the D100 driver. The D100 driver wireless access not only lets the Mactook running Leopard but as well an iBook running Tiger and a 3rd Gen iPod touch work excellently.  The color printing is better than I need. It copies and does what I generally need.

I use the HP 5520 in STANDALONE mode to provide printing service for all devices in wireless access.

To be sure here must be some functionality I do not get, given all the adverts about all the "wonderful" nuances in the product.  But most all straight forward printing and copying functionality I need for my iPod iOS4, MacBook Leopard and iBook G3 on Tiger, work excellently; they can see it as either a D100 or as a 5520.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [drivers for the HP Photosmart 5520](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareCategory?product=5157536&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en) require at least OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard).

If she has an Intel Mac, she can most likely upgrade it to [Snow Leopard for $20](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC573Z/A/mac-os-x-106-snow-leopard?find=snow%20leopard) (and from there, she can upgrade it further to OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) for free).

If she has a PowerPC Mac rather than an Intel Mac, then unfortunately she's stuck, since OS X 10.5 is the last version that supports PowerPC.

---

If she is stuck on PowerPC, you might have some luck setting up the printer as a "similar" model – that is, when you go to add the printer, select a different HP Photosmart model (assuming there are others listed). You likely won't be able to use every feature of the printer, but it could suffice depending on what your needs are.

I did this before when I was in a similar situation (official printer drivers required a newer version of OS X than what I could install), and it worked well enough, in that I could still print basic documents (but couldn't scan or anything).